# How to delete space from an nth location using sed command?

Tags: unix, sed

input:

```
B0128001594  2015081100001 RESPDTL
```

output:

```
B0128001594  2015081100001RESPDTL
```

In the above example, I need the 3rd white space to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the second *block of spaces* use:

```
$ sed 's/\s\+//2' <<< "B0128001594  2015081100001 RESPDTL"
B0128001594  2015081100001RESPDTL
#                        ^
#                        removed here
```

To remove the second space, use:

```
$ sed 's/ //2' <<< "B0128001594  2015081100001 RESPDTL"
B0128001594 2015081100001 RESPDTL
#           ^
#           removed here
```

Note the usage of `\s\+`: `\s` for a space (tab or space) and `\+` to indicate one or many.

As andlrc suggests in comments, do use `[[:space:]]` to make it POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$ sed 's/^\([^ ]* *[^ ]*\) */\1/' input
B0128001594  2015081100001RESPDTL
```

Basically it replaces the first two columns and the trailing space, with the first two columns.

So `A B C` becomes `A BC` and `A B C D` becomes `A BC D`.

Comment: Will this work for a file containing more whitespaces even after "RESPDTL" ? Because I just need the second white space removed and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, it's carefully crafted to work like that. `A B C D` becomes `A BC D`

Comment: So lets say , we have not just one space. But multiple spaces in between.
Then will this work ? for a file containing multiple lines of unknown spaces in between.

Comment: Still works. The second set of spaces will be removed, the rest will not be changed at all.

Comment: awesome thanks man.. I think I have to put in a loop for this if there are multiple lines. Am I right ?

Comment: No, sed will loop over the specified file (currently `input`).

Comment: sed 's/^\([^ ]* *[^ ]*\) /\1/' input   
---- Removed the * at the end to remove only one space between the second and the third word.

Comment: Yes? `*` will match zero or more of whats infront. In this case a space.

Answer (score 1):

How about use awk?

```
echo "B0128001594  2015081100001 RESPDTL" | awk '{print $1,$2$3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage: `awk -f f.awk file.dat`

```
$ cat f.awk
{
    match($0, /[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]/)
    print substr($0, 1, RLENGTH-1) substr($0, RLENGTH+1)
}
```